# Website deployment on Github ( using cra)

Tags: github, deployment

Actually I am trying hard to deploy my portfolio website on github ; but it is not being deployed correctly, means after deployment readme file is being opened.
Other than that npm run deploy is also not working in my visual studio code terminal.
Completely exhausted, kimdly help me out.
Firstly i am uploading my all files (i.e. public, src, etc ) excluding node modules, after that in setting, pages option and save the master or main branch, site is being assigned but only readme file opens
Is their any specific order of uploading codes in repo

I want to my website to open correctly as normal site opens